# Should I use the sql COUNT(*) or use SELECT to fetch rows and count the rows later

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, performance, query-optimization

I am writing a NodeJs application which should be very light in weight to the mysql db(Engine- InnoDB).

I am trying to count the number of records of a table in the mysql db

So I was wondering whether I should use the COUNT(*) function or get all the rows with a SELECT query and then count the rows using JavaScript.

Which way is better with respect to,

1. DB Operation cost
2. Overall performance

Comment: use the COUNT(*) function

`MyISAM does keep a count of the table rows, and can keep it accurate since the only locks MyISAM supports is a table lock.` so if your DB is myISAM, it will return quick count.

`InnoDB however supports transactions, and needs to do a table scan to count the rows.`

Comment: Will you still select all data after the select count?

Comment: No, I just want the count, subject to some constraints though(i.e- have some where clauses).

Comment: A count with a where clause must scan the relevant rows, whether it is InnoDB or MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use the `count()` function - unless you need the data within the records as well for other purpose.

If you query all rows, then on MySQL side the server has to prepare a resultset (memory consumption, time to fetch data into resultset), then push it down through the connection to your application (more data takes more time), your application has to receive the data (again, memory consumption and time to create the resultset), and finally your application has to count the number of records in the resultset.

If you use `count()`, MySQL counts records and returns just a single number.

Answer (score 1):

count(*) is obviously better than fetch and count separately.
As count(*) fetch the total count from index key (if there is any primary key).

Also the fetching data takes too much of time( disk I/O and network operations).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When getting information from a database, the usual best approach is to get what you need and nothing more. This includes things like selecting specific columns rather than `select *`, and aggregating at the DBMS rather than in your client code. In this case, since all you apparently need is a count, use `count()`.

It's a good bet that will outperform any other attempted solution since:

- you'll be sending only what's absolutely necessary over the network (this may be less important for local databases but, once you have your data elsewhere, it can have a real impact); and
- the DBMS will almost certainly be optimised for that use case.

Answer (score 1):

Do a count(FIELD_NAME) as it will be much faster when you fetch all rows .It will only get count which is always index in table.

Comment: `COUNT(field)` checks `field` for being `NULL`.  You need a `WHERE` clause for other types of limiting.